# Unsupported config option for services.db: 'images'

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to learn how to utilize docker-compose and was following instructions until I received an error. Here's my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python /usr/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=postgres
      - SQL_USER=postgres
      - SQL_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    images: postgres:10.7-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

When I go back and enter "docker-compose up -d --build", I would get an error saying

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.db: 'images'
```

I think I have the indentation correct and 'images' look okay to me.
My docker-compose version is 1.23.2 and trying to run this on Mac.
Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `image` **not** `images`.