# docker-compose: Unsupported config option for services.db: 'jupyter'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter

I am trying to learn how to utilize docker-compose and was following instructions until I received an error. Here's my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=${POSTGRESS_PASSWORD}
    jupyter:
      images: jupyter/scipy-notebook:17aba6048f44
      volume:
        - ./:/home/notebook
      ports:
        - "8888:8888"
```

When I go back and enter "docker-compose up -d --build", I would get an error saying

```
The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.db: 'jupyter'
```

My docker-compose version is 1.23.2 and trying to run this on Mac. Any ideas? thanks in advance.
I'm sorry, I'm not good at English, so I'm referring to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858549/unsupported-config-option-for-services-db-images)

Comment: sorry, My docker-compose is 1.18.0-rc2.

Comment: just backspace the entire lines up from  `jupyter:` one charachter back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit it like below

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=${POSTGRESS_PASSWORD}
  jupyter:
    image: jupyter/scipy-notebook:17aba6048f44
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/notebook
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=${POSTGRESS_PASSWORD}
  jupyter:
    image: jupyter/scipy-notebook:65761486d5d3
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/notebook
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
```

Answer (score 0):

version: '3'

services:

```
db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
        - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
        - POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=${POSTGRESS_PASSWORD}

jupyter:
    image: jupyter/scipy-notebook:17aba6048f44  # you write "images" but actually it should  be image
    volume:
        - ./:/home/notebook
    ports:
        - "8888:8888"
```